# JQuery DatePicker rendering ugly

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to implement a DatePicker using JQuery, this is my code:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js")" type="text/javascript">   </script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
@Html.TextBox("a",Model.ContractStart, new { @class = "datepicker" })

<script>

$('.datepicker').datepicker({

    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
});
</script>
```

Problem is it's rendering really ugly and not like the one they show on the tutorial...

Here's the result i get:

[image]

And heres the one from the tutorial:

http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/CommunityServer-Blogs-Components-WeblogFiles/00-00-01-03-74-metablogapi/7737.image_5F00_477473C0.png

I'm really new to JQuery... I already checked the JQuery page for this datepicker but its the same code and still it does not look like mine, what am i doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to include the CSS and images in the header of your page as well or else it can't style the calendar.

Comment: Do you have the JQuery UI CSS in your HTML as a link tag? http://www.htmlhelp.com/reference/css/style-html.html

Comment: No I did not, thank you so much now it looks great! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to include the CSS in your header. It is unable to style it without them.

```
<head>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Contect/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.css")" rel="styleshee" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js")" type="text/javascript">           </script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```